# Definite Integral inside definte integral

Tags: integration

For a physics problem, I am trying to solve the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^R\left(\int_{0}^r4\pi\rho(\tilde{r})\tilde{r}^2d\tilde{r}\right)\cdot 4\pi r^2dr$$, for an unknown function $\rho(r)$.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Solve what? I don't see an equation.

Comment: Without knowing what $\rho$ is, I don't think it's possible to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know about $\tilde{\rho}(\tilde{r})$, we can only provide a kind of solution which is "general" but not necessarily valid.

We start from the middle integral, which is of course what we need do first.

$$\int_0^r 4\pi \tilde{\rho}(\tilde{r})\tilde{r}^2\ \text{d}\tilde{r}$$

We do it by parts twice, assuming that

$$\int \tilde{\rho}(\tilde{r}) = P(\tilde{r})$$

$$\int P(\tilde{r}) = q(\tilde{r})$$

$$\int q(\tilde{r}) = Q(\tilde{r})$$

and

$$P(\tilde{r})\tilde{r}^2 = 0 ~~~~~~~~~~~ \text{when} ~~~~~ \tilde{r} = 0$$

$$q(\tilde{r})\tilde{r} = 0 ~~~~~~~~~~~ \text{when} ~~~~~ \tilde{r} = 0$$

Those are conditions which clearly are not valid in general, it depends upon what those functions will be. However for quite good function, those hold.

Then integrating by parts once with $f = \tilde{r}^2$ and $g' = \tilde{\rho}(\tilde{r})$ we get:

$$4\pi\left[r^2P(r) - \int_0^r 2\tilde{r}P(\tilde{r})\ \text{d}\tilde{r}\right]$$

Now we do by parts again for the integral, obtaining:

$$4\pi\left[r^2P(r) - 2\left(rq(r) - \int_0^r q(\tilde{r})\ \text{d}\tilde{r}\right)\right]$$

Since we don't know anything about $q$ function, we just integrate by following the fundamental theorem of calculus, that is:

$$4\pi\left[r^2P(r) - 2rq(r) + 2\left( Q(r) - Q(0) \right)\right]$$

Now we can face the final integral:

$$\int_0^R 4\pi\left[r^2P(r) - 2rq(r) + 2\left( Q(r) - Q(0) \right)\right]\cdot 4\pi r^2\ \text{d}r$$

which can be written as a sum of terms:

$$16\pi^2\left\{\int_0^R r^4P(r)\ \text{d}r - 2\int_0^R r^3Q(r)\ \text{d}r + 2\int_0^R r^2\left[Q(r) - Q(0)\right]\right\}$$

You can always integrate by parts but.. well it's useless since you don't know anything about the initial function $\tilde{\rho}$. Indeed for very bad function the whole procedure may fail at the very start of this.

Too many assumptions, too less certainties.